# Items in Tool Box are grayed out - how to Enable them?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, msbi

I'm trying to create my first report and I created a dataset and am trying to drag table from the toolbox. But it is grayed out. How to enable it? Any reason why it is happening like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually created a new report.  What you've done is create a project which can and often does contain many different reports.  These projects can also contain many data sets and data sources.  You can right-click the reports folder and create a new report which will enable those controls.